# Android NDK: How to suppress "app has only 32 bit libraries" warning

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-build

Our app has quite a good number of native libraries along with some Java classes and we are building our app for only 32-bit architecture. We are aware that Google has mandated to provide 64-bit native binaries since August 1, 2019, but currently we don't use Play Store and until we are ready with 64-bit binaries we would like to suppress the warnings which report that we are not building 64-bit native binaries.

Android Studio: 4.0.1
Cmake version: 3.10.2

So, how can I suppress these warnings, we have a lot of native binaries and for each binary these warning lines are generated. And the build window gets filled with a lot of these lines, probably each time for each native library.

Warnings which are generated in the code can be suppressed with the help of CMAKE_C_FLAGS and adding the type of warning to be suppressed, like -Wno-unknown-pragmas (suppressing only those which we are sure of). But couldn't know how to suppress this type of warning.

*WARNING: This app only has 32-bit [armeabi-v7a,x86] native libraries. Beginning August 1, 2019 Google Play store requires that all apps that include native libraries must provide 64-bit versions. For more information, visit https://g.co/64-bit-requirement
This app only has 32-bit [armeabi-v7a,x86] native libraries. Beginning August 1, 2019 Google Play store requires that all apps that include native libraries must provide 64-bit versions. For more information, visit https://g.co/64-bit-requirement*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As there seems to be no sane way to suppress warnings of this kind, I found a dirty way. Just paste this into your application's `build.gradle`, and the warning is gone. Keep in mind that this can break any time if the AGP devs choose to do some refactoring.

```
private void suppressIssue(evilString) {
    suppressIssueReport { it.contains(evilString) }
    suppressIssueLog { it.contains(evilString) }
}

private void suppressIssueReport(predicate) {
    def appPluginClass = "com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.AppPlugin"
    def syncIssueReporterClass = "com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueReporterImpl"
    def issueReporter = plugins
            .findPlugin(Class.forName(appPluginClass))
            .projectServices
            .issueReporter
    def syncIssuesField = Class.forName(syncIssueReporterClass)
            .getDeclaredField("_syncIssues")
    syncIssuesField.setAccessible(true)
    syncIssuesField.set(issueReporter, new HashMap() {
        @Override
        Object put(Object key, Object value) {
            if (!predicate(value.message)) {
                return super.put(key, value)
            } else {
                return null
            }
        }
    })
}

private void suppressIssueLog(predicate) {
    def context = Logging.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME).context
    def originalListener = context.getOutputEventListener()
    context.setOutputEventListener {
        if (!predicate(it.message)) {
            originalListener.onOutput(it)
        }
    }
}

suppressIssue("CXX5202")
```

Where this came from: [#1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/cxx/configure/AbiConfigurator.kt#163), [#2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/cxx/logging/IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment.kt#35), [#3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/errors/SyncIssueReporterImpl.kt#45)